# Resharper complains 'return' statement outside of function

Tags: ecmascript-6, resharper

In my Hello Aurelia program in VS2015 update2 Resharper 2016.1.2 complains

```
'return' statement outside of function
```

even though the app runs in the browser.

[image]

Comment: That's not an ES6 class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not a ReSharper's highlighting. That's Visual Studio's, it doesn't understand experimental ES features such as class properties.

You should disable Visual Studio's highlightings in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JavaScript -> IntelliSense.

ReSharper fully supports experimental ES features, so when you'll disable VS highlightings, everything should work fine.

Comment: ReSharper needs an alt+enter quick fix on those errors to disable VS highlighting :)

Comment: @citizenmatt I think that ReSharper will disable VS highlightings for JavaScript by default relatively soon. :)

Comment: I don't see an option for highlightings in Tools->Optoins->Text Editor->Javascript->Intellisense

Do you mean the check box "Show syntax errors"?